# Inductor potential difference direction

Tags: electric-circuits, induction, inductance

If you have increasing current going down an inductor, the inductor will produce a potential difference to produce a counter current in the opposite direction, or up. The lower potential is then on the top of the inductor. However, the net current is still going down, which is higher potential. How can net current go from lower to higher potential?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have increasing current going down an inductor, the inductor will have an induced electric field going up to resist the current increase. Since a perfect conductor has 0 net electric field, the electrostatic charges in the circuit will rearrange such that the electrostatic electric field points down and has equal magnitude to the induced electric field.

The voltage potential only accounts for the electrostatic electric field. Hence since the electrostatic electric field points down the bottom of the inductor has a lower voltage than the top.

Hence the OP's statement that the bottom of the inductor has a higher voltage is incorrect, and the current is still going from high to low voltage.

Comment: The fact that a perfect conductor has 0 net electric field is true if the conductor is not connected to a power source that is constantly maintaining potential difference between two points on a conductor. A battery is an example of such power source and if you connect a battery to a conductor then there will be net electric field in the conductor as long as battery has the power to maintain potential difference.

Comment: Now the answer given by @Duncan Harris is completely correct and what I believe you are confused at is the fact that still the main power source would dominate over the induced EMF of inductor and hence current is flowing in correct direction

Comment: @Ritanshu Imagine a 0 resistance resistor and a 1 kOhm resistor connected in series  to a battery. All of the voltage drop will fall across the 1 kOhm resistor. Hence the 0 resistance resistor (the perfect conductor) will still have 0 electric field

Comment: To clarify on what I was confused about. I knew that the main power source would dominate over the induced EMF. What I was confused about is that I thought the net electric field inside the inductor was equal to the induced electric field (but actually it is induced+ electrostatic = 0). And I thought that voltage difference was the work from the net electric field (but actually it is just from electrostatic)

Comment: So by perfect conductor you meant a "super conductor" ? In that case the law which you are using to calculate voltage and current aka Ohm's law doesn't work. Because the resistance becomes 0 and you know what happens dividing by 0. But even in case of a super conductor it is possible to have a finite amount of current and that is LC Oscillation. Anyways, If you got the answer then maybe you should change your answer and correct it.

Comment: @Ritanshu By perfect conductor I meant 0 resistance, which I suppose a super conductor fits. You don't need to divide by 0, you can do V=IR. Since R=0, V=0. I don't understand what correction you are suggesting I include.

Comment: I meant that first paragraph of your answer is not clear enough, you should clarify it. Probably you should check out answering guidelines of the website and you will get a good idea there

Answer (score 3):

Your initial supposition, "If you have increasing current going down an inductor,..." is a bit vague about exactly what external influences are at work on the inductor in question.  I will suppose that the current through the inductor is increasing because a battery has just been connected directly to the inductor.  Other suppositions are possible, but this is a very simple explanation for the increasing current, and the concepts at play would be similar in any other more complicated circuit.

At the moment the battery is connected to the inductor, no current has been flowing through the inductor, so it has been producing no potential difference of its own.  And the battery is applying a higher voltage to the top of the inductor than the bottom.  So current will begin to increase in the downward direction.  How quickly is it increasing?  As quickly as the inductor will allow it to increase, because the more quickly the current is increasing, the more counter-voltage the inductor produces, and the less voltage there is to push the current.  Specifically, the current increases at precisely the rate for which the inductor voltage cancels out the battery voltage exactly, allowing all of the classic circuit diagram laws to be satisfied.

We do not grow up experiencing inductors directly on an everyday basis, so to intuitively understand their behavior, an analogy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_analogy) to mechanics is often useful:

Inductors resist changes in the current passing through them, just as a large mass resists changes in its velocity.  Your question is analagous to asking how an object being accelerated by an external force can ever move, since it always produces an equal and opposite reaction force opposing its direction of acceleration.

Comment: The direction of the inductor counter-voltage confuses me. The counter voltage should be the opposite direction of the battery voltage, right? If the battery applies a higher voltage to the top than the bottom of the inductor, then the inductor counter-voltage should have a higher voltage at the bottom than the top of the inductor, right?

Comment: Yes, using the "voltage" terminology that is right.  It is much less confusing if you consider that the inductor is creating a "potential difference", while the battery is applying an "electro-motive force" or "emf".  I would look up the distinction between these things.

Comment: So the battery produces an electro-motive force on the inductor leading to increasing downward current. The inductor wishes to produce a potential difference to counter this, which would be lower potential on top and higher on bottom? I am still confused after searching up and using these new terms. If the inductor has lower potential on top, how can current be flowing downwards?

Comment: Yeah it can be confusing.  Imagine water being pumped up a vertical pipe.  The gravitational potential is highest at the top of the pipe.  But the pressure of the water is highest at the bottom of the pipe, which pushes it up.  The pressure is like the voltage produced by the emf of the battery.  The gravitational potential is like the effect of the inductor.

Comment: But my electrical engineering class professor says current always flows from higher to lower potential. Is that incorrect then?

Comment: No, that is correct.  I may have confused things with my proliferation of terminology.  From a circuit measurement (ie most electrical engineering) perspective one can forget about the force that an inductor exerts on electrons and just treat the inductor as a resistor where the resistance is proportional to the rate of change of the current.  The voltage drop across the inductor will be equal to the battery's voltage, so the current will increase at a constant rate.

Comment: Rather than thinking of the inductor as pushing backwards when current increases (which is true, but apparently confusing), think of the voltage applied to the inductor as defining the rate of change in the current.   The inductor will appear to have whatever resistance(s) are necessary to produce the current profile which matches the voltage.

Comment: I want to understand what is actually happening though. The resistance sounds like a cheat? I found this from the textbook which I think is causing my confusion

Comment: Because current i is changing, there is a self-induced emf in the inductor. The direction of emf is upward because current i is downward through the inductor and increasing. Thus, as we move from top to bottom, opposite the direction we encounter a potential change of - L di/dt.

Comment: I've edited the reference for clarity. Apparently, the emf is upwards but the potential difference is the opposite direction, downwards? Why is that?

Comment: If the inductor were a battery, drawn so that its emf is upwards, then the top terminal would be positive and the bottom terminal negative, so the potential drop would be from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The counter potential difference you are talking about is indeed produced but it is mostly smaller than the dominant potential difference (such as potential different due to a battery) due to which current was increasing and hence the net current will still flow in the same direction because the initial source of potential difference overcomes the opposing potential difference but definitely the current is reduced than it would have been. It's is based on Lenz's.

Answer (score 0):

the inductor has an electrostatic field and a non-electrostatic field inside its metal, which balance and cause a zero electric field in the metal of the inductor. It's zero since the inductor is assumed to have approximately zero resistance, so for the current density in the equation J= conductivity . E to have a finite value, the electric field must go to zero, since the conductivity goes to infinity. Now, where did the potential difference come from? Remember that a potential difference is defined for electrostatic fields, and because the two fields balance, the potential difference is going to be the opposite direction of the induced electromotive force and same magnitude.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).